# can't get html to link while using django

Tags: python, html, css, django

If anyone can help me on why my html wont link with my css that would be awesome! Thanks!
I'm using Django 3.0.2 to make a website for a resume and I have already rooted my static files and that didn't seem to do anything. I have tried stopping and running my server multiple times as well as find solutions online but everyone is using an older version or their solutions don't help.

HTML:

```
<head>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/base/styles.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    this is a test
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            {% include 'navbar.html' %}
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(82, 70, 70);
}

.container{
    background-color: rgb(128, 199, 172);
}

.navbar{
    background-color: rosybrown;
}
```

SETTINGS:

```
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    '/pydir/mysite/static',
]

STATIC_ROOT = '/pydir/mysite/static'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and I made sure that staticfiles and admin where in the installed apps.

FOLDER STRUCTURE:

```
├───mysite
│   │   asgi.py
│   │   settings.py
│   │   urls.py
│   │   wsgi.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │   
│   └───__pycache__
│           settings.cpython-37.pyc
│           urls.cpython-37.pyc
│           wsgi.cpython-37.pyc
│           __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│           
├───pages
│   │   admin.py
│   │   apps.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   tests.py
│   │   views.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │   
│   ├───migrations
│   │       __init__.py
│   │       
│   └───__pycache__
│           views.cpython-37.pyc
│           __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│           
├───projects
│   │   admin.py
│   │   apps.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   tests.py
│   │   views.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │   
│   ├───migrations
│   │   │   0001_initial.py
│   │   │   __init__.py
│   │   │   
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   │           0001_initial.cpython-37.pyc
│   │           __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │           
│   └───__pycache__
│           admin.cpython-37.pyc
│           models.cpython-37.pyc
│           __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│           
├───static
│   ├───base
│   │       styles.css
│   │       
│   └───images
└───templates
        home.html
        navbar.html
```

Comment: try to put the {% load static %} in the top of the file

Comment: tried moving it but still nothing :/

Comment: did u do the command python manage.py collectstatic

Comment: yeah, it created a folder named admin in my static folder and said that it copied 130 files to it. My css file isn't in it tho so idk if I am supposed to put it in the new folder

Comment: Where is your `styles.css` file? Is this on your development environment (DEBUG=True)? Note that `STATIC_ROOT` should not be the same as any of the static folders of your app, i.e. you can't have /pydir/mysite/static both in `STATICFILES_DIR` and as `STATIC_ROOT`.

Comment: Easiest would be to show the folder structure of your project, which visibly shows the location of styles.css.

Comment: so i fixed the static root and debug is set to true. I tried again after the static root but nothing changed. I did find that the error that its giving me is 404 and its saying that it cant find the styles.css file.

Comment: also i dont know how to show folder structure

Comment: nvm i figured it out, just edited the original post and I just got rid of static root since i really dont know what to path it to...

Comment: ok so idk if its progress but i got it to find the style but it now says that it wont apply the style because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue! it was the folder order. I had the static folder on the outside of my apps because I was treating it like the templates folder but I had to move it to an app for it to work. Thanks for the help tho!